# Check if the current shortcode is being used in a widget

Tags: widgets, shortcode, conditional-tags

How can I check if the current shortcode is being used in a widget? I need to disable some shortcode options that are not allowed in a widget.

Someone know how?

Answer (score 1):

There are two hooks, [widget_text](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_text/) and [dynamic_sidebar_params](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/dynamic_sidebar_params/). You can use one of them.

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'wpse219770_filter_widget_text', 1, 3 );
    function wpse219770_filter_widget_text( $widget_text, $instance, $widget )
    {
        $tag = 'bartag';//shortcode tag
        if ( 'text-2' == $widget->id && has_shortcode( $instance['text'], $tag ) )
            remove_shortcode( $tag );
        else
            add_shortcode( $tag, 'bartag_func' );

        return $widget_text;
    }
```

Or you can use this methode:

```
add_action( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', 'wpse219770_dynamic_sidebar_params_hook', 1, 1 );
function wpse219770_dynamic_sidebar_params_hook( $content )
{
    //print_r( $content ) and use it for conditional

    $tag = 'bartag';
    if ( shortcode_exists( $tag ) )
        remove_shortcode( $tag );

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Ty for reply, but I was more looking for a conditional that can be used in a callback of a shortcode. Conditional checks if the current shortcode is in sidebar /widget, similar functions like: is_singular(), is_front_page(). Is it possible?

Comment: First I need to know.. did you create your own shortcode or it come from other plugin?

Comment: It's my own shortcode.

Comment: Oh OK, since there are no direct function like your mention, I think you just need to focus in another area. Example if you just need to add shortcode in loop, just use conditional [in_the_loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_the_loop) inside your shortcode function.

Comment: Yes, I was using in_the_loop with is_singular, but the shortcode can also be used outside the loop (in the header). I am trying to disable option (rich snippet) that is unnecessary in a widget. Ty for the replies so far.

Comment: maybe you need to add your shortcode function here, how they call.

Comment: No need for that. Ty for your replies but it didn't help me.

Comment: I solved it by adding an extra shortcode attribute in shortcode, this way I can have control if i'm inserting a shortcode inside a widget.

Comment: Great. Do you use shortcode name and fire [shortcode_atts_{$shortcode}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/shortcode_atts_shortcode/) ? it will help to control your shortocode too.